# Stackview replace qml after button animation is completed

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

i am building an interface with QtQuick2 by using qmls. I also created a few buttons on home page and i am trying to change qmls by using loader after some animation is played. I have a stackview like this:

```
StackView {
    id: stackViewTool
    anchors {
        left: parent.left
        right: parent.right
        top: parent.top
        bottom: bottomBar.top
    }
    initialItem: initializePage
    
}
```

and i also added "initializePage" variable as property

```
property string initializePage : "HomePage.qml"
```

here is how i use my button to change qml on some other pages.

```
    SimpleButton {
        id:homeClicked
        Image{
            id: homeID
            source:"/images/barHome.png"
        }
        onClicked: {
            stackViewTool.replace(initializePage)
        }

    }
```

I want to add a animation to get the "pushing button" feeling. I want to change the button image first, and then i want to replace the qml. Here is the sequental animation i want to use. I want to have the animation like pushed and released, then change the qml.

```
            SequentialAnimation {
            id : homePressed
            PropertyAnimation {
                targets: [homeID]
                property: "source"
                to: "/images/pressedHome.png"
            }

              PauseAnimation {
                duration: 100
            }

              PropertyAnimation {
                  targets: [homeID]
                  property: "source"
                  to: "/images/barHome.png"
              }

              PauseAnimation {
                duration: 100
              }

        }
```

I tried to use **"*stackViewTool.replace(initializePage)*"** after the sequential animation but it did not work. I tried to add **"*Component.onCompleted: stackViewTool.replace(initializePage)*"** after 100ms pause snippet(last step of animation) but it did not work. What can i do for create something like i wanted? Answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the `onFinished` | `onStarted` signal handlers.
2. You can use [ScriptAction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-scriptaction.html) at the end of the animation:

```
SequentialAnimation
{
    id: homePressed
    PropertyAnimation {
        targets: [homeID]
        property: "source"
        to: "/images/pressedHome.png"
    }

    PauseAnimation {
        duration: 100
    }

    PropertyAnimation {
        targets: [homeID]
        property: "source"
        to: "/images/barHome.png"
    }

    PauseAnimation {
        duration: 100
    }
    ScriptAction{
        script: function(){stackViewTool.replace(initializePage)}

   }
}
```